# Execute query with @parameter that is autodefined and not neccesary to pass with Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: mysql, vb.net

VB.NET ask por @rownum1 definition executing this query:

```
qry = "SELECT @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum, fld1, fld1 FROM ( SELECT @rownum1:=0 ) r, tablename WHERE fld2='some_value' ORDER BY fld2"
```

but I define it with 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rownum1", 0) 
and MySQL replace @rownum1 with 0.

I tried declaring @rownum1 in the query and not using AddWithValue, but it doesn´t work:

```
qry = "SET @rownum1:=0; SELECT @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum, fld1, fld1 FROM ( SELECT @rownum1:=0 ) r, tablename WHERE fld2='some_value' ORDER BY fld2"
```

Here is my code:

```
qry = "SELE...."
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, conbd)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rownum1", 0)
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `Allow User Variables=True` in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AddWithValue` if you don't want to provide a value.  Don't use it at all, but that's a different conversation.  If you want to add a parameter then call `Add`.  If the purpose of the parameter is to pass a value out then set the `Direction` as well, because the default is `Input`.

Comment: In fact, I don´t need the parameter... it is used within de query only to add 1 to each row number. I don't need to pass any value to it. But if I don't use `AddWithValue`, I got this error: `Parameter '@rownum' must be defined`.
I If add `cmd.Parameters.Add("@rownum")` I got this error: `Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored`

Comment: So maybe use an overload of `Add` that actually exists.  Do you see any overload that has one parameter of type `String`?  Read the documentation, pay attention to Intellisense and turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and your IDE options.